# Could not get unknown property 'navigationVersion'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack

I am trying to import Android jetpack libraries into my project but I am getting this error while trying to do so.

[image]

The code I used to implement jetpack navigation library inside "build.gradle(module:app)" file

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because You haven't defined that property. Set it in `gradle.properties` or change this `$rootProject.navigationVersion` to current version. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx).

[image]

Comment: exactly what should be done and is explained in simple words.. nice.. tq